# Ubuntu signed Grub do not prefix tftp-root directory for tftp requests

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

```
$ lsb_release -rd
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release: 14.04

dpkg -l grub-efi-amd64-signed
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name Version Architecture Description
+++-======================-================-================-=================================================
iU grub-efi-amd64-signed 1.34+2.02~beta2- amd64 GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 ve
```

Grub requests for files to tftpserver are not prefixed with tftproot. Though 'prefix' variable is set. This is being observed in UEFI boot mode. This leads to boot failure as grub is unable to fetch grub.cfg

Relevant O/p from grub prompt:

```
prefix=(tftp,10.10.1.13)/grub
root=tftp,10.10.1.13
pxe_default_server=10.10.1.13
net_default_ip=10.10.1.161
net_default_mac=a0:d3:c1:fb:86:94
net_default_server:10.10.1.13
grub_cpu=x86_64
grub_platform=efi
```

tcpdump o/p

```
1382 17:33:56.955465 IP 10.10.1.161.25300 > 10.10.1.13.tftp: 58 RRQ "/grub/x86_64-efi/command.lst" octet blksiz e 1024 tsize 0
1383 17:33:56.956640 IP 10.10.1.13.45600 > 10.10.1.161.25300: UDP, length 24
1384 17:33:56.956885 IP 10.10.1.161.25301 > 10.10.1.13.tftp: 53 RRQ "/grub/x86_64-efi/fs.lst" octet blksize 102 4 tsize 0
1385 17:33:56.958146 IP 10.10.1.13.42098 > 10.10.1.161.25301: UDP, length 24
1386 17:33:56.958368 IP 10.10.1.161.25302 > 10.10.1.13.tftp: 57 RRQ "/grub/x86_64-efi/crypto.lst" octet blksize 1024 tsize 0
1387 17:33:56.959412 IP 10.10.1.13.33848 > 10.10.1.161.25302: UDP, length 24
1388 17:33:56.959646 IP 10.10.1.161.25303 > 10.10.1.13.tftp: 59 RRQ "/grub/x86_64-efi/terminal.lst" octet blksi ze 1024 tsize 0
1389 17:33:56.961969 IP 10.10.1.13.47148 > 10.10.1.161.25303: UDP, length 24
1390 17:33:56.962482 IP 10.10.1.161.25304 > 10.10.1.13.tftp: 44 RRQ "/grub/grub.cfg" octet blksize 1024 tsize 0
1391 17:33:56.966059 IP 10.10.1.13.38281 > 10.10.1.161.25304: UDP, length 24
```

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to move the root of the tftp server to /grub to match the prefix assigned by the signed bootloader.

```
/etc/default/tftpd-hpa:
OPTIONS="-v -s /grub"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/grub"
```

Can you see the grub.cfg file from grub?

```
grub> cat (tftp,10.10.1.13)/grub/grub.cfg
```

or

```
grub> cat (tftp,10.10.1.13)/grub.cfg
```

I also found it helpful for debugging the file to  do the following:

```
grub> configfile (tftp,10.10.1.13)/grub/grub.cfg
error: can't find command 'kernel'
error: can't find command 'append'
...
```

You can use this to check the syntax for your file.